# nmap not outputting one line to console when using -oG

Tags: debian, nmap

when I run:

```
nmap --open -sT -p 5900,3389 -oG test 10.0.1.121
```

This outputs to console:

```
Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-02-15 16:31 PST
Interesting ports on 10.0.1.121:
Not shown: 1 filtered port
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3389/tcp open  ms-term-serv
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:E1:16:55 (VMware)
```

And this outputs to `test`:

```
# Nmap 5.00 scan initiated Fri Feb 15 16:31:56 2013 as: nmap --open -sT -p 5900,3389 -oG test 10.0.1.121 
Host: 10.0.1.121 () Ports: 3389/open/tcp//ms-term-serv///   Ignored State: filtered (1)
# Nmap done at Fri Feb 15 16:31:57 2013 -- 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.52 seconds
```

I want to run `awk` on the output to the console not from the file. It seems like for everyone else it outputs to to console. I don't know why this isn't working for me.

Running nmap 5.000

Answer (score 1):

As a special case, a file name of - can be used to send the Grepable output to the console instead of the normal output.